# Fix sourcing each package separately with catkin_make_isolated

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using `catkin_make_isolated` to build my workspace. Whenever I create a new catkin package, I have to add `source ~/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/package_name/setup.bash` to my ~/.bashrc otherwise I cannot run any nodes from that package. I get errors such as `[mobility_bringup_all.launch] is neither a launch file in package [mobility_bringup] nor is [mobility_bringup] a launch file name`.

Only using `source ~/catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash` and `source ~/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/setup.bash` doesn't work.

EDIT: If I source multiple `~/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/package_name/setup.bash` in my ~/.bashrc, I cannot run any nodes from any of the packages. If I only source one package's `setup.bash`, I can run that package's nodes. The problem is the same as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069147/roslaunch-failed-cannot-launch-node). It seems the source commands are being overwritten? Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268489/fix-sourcing-each-package-separately-with-catkin_make_isolated/) by [mmy227](https://answers.ros.org/users/30437/mmy227/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-10**:
Not an answer, but is there any reason you're not using [catkin_tools](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools)?

**Comment by [mmy227](https://answers.ros.org/users/30437/mmy227/) on 2017-08-10**:
I'm using catkin_make_isolated because I installed Google Cartographer and that's what they said to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you use `catkin_make_isolated --install`, you need to source `~/catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2017-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0